# ASP.Net auto-generated Admin tool

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create an administrative site for managing my web site's db. I don't want to build this myself, I simply want the framework in place so that I can add customization myself after it is in place.

Django has a great auto-generated admin. What's an equivalent auto-generated admin site built under asp.net?

Comment: You might be able to get some inspiration from this article for a Winforms runtime object editor http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14292/Runtime-Object-Editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/

Scaffolding (CRUD) for all tables, or optionally only the ones you choose.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/) to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at IronSpeed Designer (www.ironspeed.com).